# Displaying one value and sending another to backend with HTML <select> and <option> tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, typescript, django-rest-framework

I'm making a note-taking web app. The rich text editor includes a drop-down menu containing the names of each of the user's notebooks, so that the user can choose where the note will go. So far so good. The problem is that, in theory, the user could name two notebooks the same thing. So when the user chooses a notebook, the frontend ultimately needs to send the ID slug associated with that specific notebook to the backend, so that Django can choose which notebook to associate the note with without ambiguity.

The problem is that I don't know how to make the HTML `<select>` and `<option>` tags do what I want them to. I tried putting in one value between the HTML tags (so that it's displayed) and passing the ID as the tag's `value` attribute, but this doesn't seem to work:

```js
setNotebooks(notebookList.map(item => {
  return (
    <option value={item.notebook_id}>
      {item.name}
    </option>
);
```

When I set `notebooks` in the way I showed above, it comes back as undefined. In the example, `notebookList` is an array of objects containing each notebook's attributes.

I tried wrapping each `<option>` tag in the `<select>` one in a higher-order component with its own state that would allow me to store the ID there, but this doesn't seem to work either.

How can I associate each plaintext name with its respective ID slug, so that the frontend will know which ID to pass to the backend, while still showing the user the plaintext name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `react-select` package had everything I needed. I can generate `<option>` tags based on objects I create, and when I try to assign values to state It Just Works™:

```js
export function SelectNotebook({ currentNotebook, notebookOptions, setCurrentNotebook }) {
  const customStyles = {
    control: base => ({
      ...base,
      width: 300,
      minWidth: 300,
    })
  }

  return (
    <Select
      options={notebookOptions}
      value={currentNotebook}
      onChange={option => setCurrentNotebook(option)}
      placeholder='Select Notebook...'
      styles={customStyles}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not expert in react but i think you need to set `value="somevariable"` attribute in `select` element which will hold current selected `option` value.

Comment: Already tried it. When I do that, it tells me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` .

Comment: You need to call `somevariable` but i think you try to call something like `select.value` attribute.